# Understanding flutter memory view

Tags: flutter, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have some trouble understanding flutter memory view. Exploring my app memory snapshot, I see that there are too many instances of some widgets.

[image: Snapshot]

Like CollectionScreen, for example. I expect to see only one, this points to a leak. But Count for every instance = 0. What does it mean?

Looking at the right, I have only 2 values, one is a ValueNotifier and another is a "data" class. Both should not be holding references to the widget itself or anything else.

In Android memory view, I could always check what objects does leaked instances holds references too, and then explore those objects to see what references to they hold also. How can I do the same way with Flutter?

Also, going back to the leak, Collection was passed as a parameter to the CollectionScreen when I created it. Should I somehow null the reference when destroying the widget to avoid the leak? What is holding my CollectionScreen in memory?